# How to be a command in SQL using LIKE?

Tags: sql, command

I want to select records where a field (varchar (45)) contains one and only one letter x and the field length is greater than 20

Comment: Well, I suggest writing some code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL you can do:

```
SELECT * FROM tablename WHERE fieldname REGEXP '^[x]{20,}$'
```

Comment: Thank you, but is there any way to do the same?, but only using the "LIKE"?